# Azure DevOps MS-Hosted agent querying a website that is locked down to an internal IP only?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-build-task, whitelist

Currently we have a scenario where:

- We have a website that we want to query as part of our build pipeline. This website is locked down to our VPN range only.
- We use Microsoft Hosted Agent as part of a build to go query said website.

Problem: It's 403'ing because the IP is not in the range.

I've looked at the organisation and the region and when I test the IP that is being used in the agent build, it's not in the list at all.

There has to be a better way to manage this, surely? I can't be changing a list of Access rules weekly to be 1 of 100...

What is everyone else doing? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked into creating a VM -> make sure the VM can ping your URL -> create a managed Identiy for that VM and use it as a self-hosted agent instead of using MS hosted agents?

Comment: Thanks for this - is there a guide I can follow on how to set this up in our DevOps organisation?

Comment: Refer this to create your self hosted Agent to use in your devops organization : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/host-build-agent/

Comment: Thank you! :) I'll look at this module!

Comment: Hi rcforster Does my answer help? Please check it and kindly let us know the result. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

By reference to this doc: [Networking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#networking), which states that "`You cannot use private connections such as ExpressRoute or VPN to connect Microsoft-hosted agents to your corporate network. The traffic between Microsoft-hosted agents and your servers will be over public network.`"

In addition, you could follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#to-identify-the-possible-ip-ranges-for-microsoft-hosted-agents) to identify the possible IP ranges for [Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). To obtain the complete list of possible IP ranges for your agent, you must use the IP ranges from all of the regions that are contained in your geography.

BTW, because Azure DevOps uses the Azure global network, IP ranges vary over time. As Rimaz commented, it is recommended to use [Self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install), which own static IP, then you don't need to update your VPN range frequently.

Comment: Thanks for this - when I say locked down to our VPN, I mean we have a bunch of IP's that are our VPN ips, that are included in the Access Restriction for the Web App - if I was to add the IP of the agent to that, wouldn't that still work? It's on the internet as such, it's just access/denied by our ip range.

Comment: Microsoft-hosted agent doesn't own static IP and it is discarded after one use. So you could use Self-hosted agent, which is deployed locally, so it owns static IP, and then add the IP to your VPN allowed list.

Comment: Thanks for that, ca you confirm what the IP will be for self hosted agents? Or is it documented.

Comment: The IP for self-hosted agent should be the same IP as the deployed machine. It is just a new service in deployed machine. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/proxy?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows for details.